# Web App login redirecting to homepage on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, authentication, elastic-beanstalk

I've hosted my application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. The application behaves itself in a local environment and shared hosting environment, but when on AWS it refuses to login. Instead it redirects back to the homepage.

Since this only happens on AWS I suspect the configuration of the EC2 instance, but I'm not aware of what could be causing this.

Aside from accepting default settings from Elastic Beanstalk, I've overridden some php.ini settings:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
mode: "000644"
owner: ec2-user
group: ec2-user
content: |
    error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING
    display_errors = On
    post_max_size = 32M
    enable_dl = On
```

What might be causing this behaviour and what can I use to diagnose the problem on AWS?